# unable to find the control that opens in background in codedui

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am currently working on AX form for automation . In one of the forms, I am trying to click a button , which opens another form and on this form  I need to perform some action.

The window which I am opening on button click sometime opens in background and few times pop up in the foreground above the window where I have  clicked the button.

I would want my window to open in the foreground so that I can perform operation , since it is opening in background the codedui playback is searching for the controls on the main window/parent  window, which making test case fail

This is making my test case fails multiple times. I am using SetFocus property and SearchInMinimizedwindow options but none of them is working

Is there any solution to always get the window on foreground in codedui or in c#

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect the popup window has some of the same automation properties as the parent window. If not able to fix this code side by using a different AutomationId, you may be able to workaround this by specifiying this is a different window instance.

```
SecondWindow.SearchProperties["Instance"] = 2;
SecondWindow.SetFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

The window that opens when you click the button, is that the child window of the Main window or does it exist on its own? Based on that, you will have to search on the parent (Main Window or Desktop).